# How to update a point table when a polygon table is modified

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to create a function that update table A (point) when table B (polygon) is modified. The reference to B must be changed in A. I can't get it to work. There are no overlaps in the polygons. It really is just to update the polygon ID in the points table. I was thinking of ST_Within to do it.

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maj_A()
>     RETURNS trigger AS $foo$    
> BEGIN
>     UPDATE public.Points AS A
>     SET A.a = B.a, 
>         A.b = B.b
>     FROM public.Polygons AS B
>     WHERE ST_WITHIN(Points.geom, Polygons.geom) AND NEW.geom <> OLD.geom;
>     RETURN NEW;
> END;
>
> $foo$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

I am using postgre 10 and postgis 2.4. Any working function is welcome. The function is linked to a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Would make a comment, but don't have enough reputation, sorry.

Shouldn't  `NEW` and `OLD` be `B` and ? `B_new` or something like this? Where is the new geometry stored to make the `ST_Within` check?

If I missed something and you want to compare geometries as in `NEW.geom <> OLD.geom`, consider [ST_Equals](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html) or [ST_OrderingEquals](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrderingEquals.html) like `ST_OrderingEquals(NEW.geom, OLD.geom) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The following code answers my need.

https://gist.github.com/neogis-de/a1d08c38d8b9c5d316c7

It updates a points layer based on the modification of an overlapping polygons, wheter it's attibute or geometry. It only attributes a polygon reference to underlying points without changing anything to a point that was in it and isn't anymore.